# Bootstrap Datepicker date difference and reservation calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am building a simple reservation system which takes:
1. The difference of Days in Bootstrap Datepicker (failed)
2. The number of rooms from a combo box (succeeded)
3. The room price ($200)
Finally, all the 3 values are multiplied and displayed in an Input "grandtotal".
I have tried several methods but since I am new to javascript, I am having some troubles.  Can you all help me and guide me through this process? 

The "grandtotal" must be calculated automatically once the user selects the dates and number of rooms.  The script coding for the calculation of days also is working incorrectly.
I will need further help so maybe, I can contact you.  Thanks again.

1.User selects the Check-in and Check-out date using Bootstrap Datepicker after which he/she selects of the number of rooms.  As the user selects, the input "grandtotal" must be updated automatically.

```
<form method="post" action="reservation.php">
  <input id="from" name="checkin" type="text" id="from"/>
  <input id="to" name="checkout" type="text" id="to"/>
  <select onchange="ChooseContact(this)" name="numrooms" id="rooms">
    <option value="1">1 room</option>
    <option value="2">2 rooms</option>
   </select>
  <select class="hidden" name="price">
          <option selected="selected">200</option>
  </select>
</form>

// this displays the respective values for selecting the dates, the number of rooms and finally, the "grandtotal" is shown automatically.
<input readonly id="totaldays" placeholder="1">
<input readonly id="totalrooms" placeholder="1">
<input readonly id="grandtotal" placeholder="-">

// bootstrap datepicker configuration 
<script>
$(function() {
var dates = $( "#from, #to" ).datepicker({
defaultDate: "+0w",
changeMonth: false,
numberOfMonths: 1,
dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
minDate: '01-10-2016',
maxDate: '31-10-2016',
});
});
</script>

// bootstrap datepicker days calculation and total rooms assigned to input
<script>
$(function() {    
$('.datepicker').datepicker({format: "dd-mm-yyyy"});
var calculateDuration = function() {
    var startDate = new Date($('#from').val());
    var endDate = new Date($('#to').val());
    var diff = endDate - startDate;
    document.getElementById('totaldays').value = (Number(diff) / 86400000) +1;  
}
$('#from').change(calculateDuration);
$('#to').change(calculateDuration);
});

function ChooseContact(data) {
var totalrooms = data.value;
document.getElementById ("totalrooms").value = (Number(totalrooms));
}
</script>
```

That`s all, I do not know how to assigned each input (totaldays, totalrooms, grandtotal) when the user clicks on each value and how to do the grandtotal calculation.

Comment: whats happening now?? what values you get??

Comment: Hi @RohitS, if i select dates from 01/10/2016 and 02/10/2016, it shows 32 days

Comment: hey hi, its because your second param is date itself not month so it should be something like '10/01/2016' && '10/02/2016'

Comment: sorry, where? Rohit

Comment: the input you give to your textfields from & to should be something like mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: Thanks I solved the date problem

Comment: Now how can I make the multiplication using the variables?  The variables are from different functions

Comment: declare them globally and use them in methods.. at the beginning  of your script declare variable like from ,to  totalrooms,grandtotal and use them in your method

Answer (score 1):

Hey Sorry for Late ans but here is something i tried with your code with few changes (initialize with default values,few functions) and it worked fine for me..yes you can go ahead and improve it further.....hope it helps :D

```js
$().ready(function() {
var dates = $( "#from, #to" ).datepicker({
showOtherMonths: false,
selectOtherMonths: false,
});
  
  var dt=new Date();
  var today= "";
  today=dt.getDate()+"/";
  today+=dt.getMonth()+1+"/";
  today+=dt.getFullYear()+"";

  var tom="";
  tom=dt.getDate()+"/";
  tom+=(dt.getMonth()+2)+"/";
  tom+=dt.getFullYear()+"";
  $("#from").val(today); 
 $("#to").val(tom); 
  getDatediff();
  Bill();
});
$('#from,#to').change(function(){
  getDatediff();
});


function getDatediff()
{
    var startDate = new Date($('#from').val());
    var endDate = new Date($('#to').val());
    var diff = endDate - startDate;
    var res=(Number(diff) / 86400000);
      if(res>0)
        {
    $('#totaldays').val(res);
        }
      else
    {
       $('#totaldays').val(0);
    }
    Bill();
}
$("#from ,#to").change(function(){
  getDatediff();
});

function Bill()
{
 var rooms= $("#totalrooms").val();
 var days=$('#totaldays').val();
 var amt=$('#price option:selected').text();
 var sum=rooms*days*amt;
  $("#grandtotal").val(sum);
}

$('#rooms').change(function(){
  $('#totalrooms').val($(this).find('option:selected').val())
  getDatediff();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"   integrity="sha256-eGE6blurk5sHj+rmkfsGYeKyZx3M4bG+ZlFyA7Kns7E="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<form method="post" action="reservation.php">
From:<input id="from" name="checkin" type="text" id="from" value=""/><br/>
To:<input id="to" name="checkout" type="text" id="to"/><br/>
Select Rooms:<select  name="numrooms" id="rooms">
    <option value="1" selected>1 room</option>
    <option value="2">2 rooms</option>
   </select><br/>
Select Price:<select class="hidden" name="price" id="price">
          <option selected="selected">200</option>
  </select><br/><br/><br/>
Your Details <br/><br/>
Days:<input readonly id="totaldays" placeholder="1" value="1"><br/>
Rooms:<input readonly id="totalrooms" placeholder="1" value="1"><br/>
GrandTotal:<input readonly id="grandtotal" placeholder="0.0">
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution.

Your negative amount of days is fixed.
If there is an impossible range of dates, an error is shown in red.
The total price is calculated.

Feel free to ask about anything in this code if there is something you don't get.
;)

```js
var roomPrice = 200;

// bootstrap datepicker configuration 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#from, #to" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+0w",
        changeMonth: false,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        minDate: '01-10-2016',
        maxDate: '31-10-2016'
    });
});

function ChooseContact(data) {
    var totalrooms = data.value;
    document.getElementById ("totalrooms").value = (Number(totalrooms));
}


function calculateDuration() {
    var diff = 0;
    if(startDate !="" && endDate !=""){
        var startDate = new Date($('#from').val());
        var endDate = new Date($('#to').val());
        diff = endDate - startDate;
    }

    if(diff==0){
        $("#totaldays").val( "1" );
        $("#grandtotal").val("").css("color","black");
    }
    if(diff>1){
        $("#totaldays").val( (diff / 86400000) +1)
        $("#grandtotal").val("").css("color","black");
    }
    if(diff<0){
        $("#totaldays").val( (diff / 86400000) -1);
        $("#grandtotal").val("Error in dates...").css("color","red");
    }
    return;
}

function grandTotal(){
    calculateDuration();
    var days = $("#totaldays").val();
    var rooms = $("#totalrooms").val();

    if( days != "" && parseInt(days) >0 ){
        if( rooms != "" ){
            var total = parseInt(days) * parseInt(rooms) * roomPrice;
            $("#grandtotal").val(total.toFixed(2)).css("color","black");
        }else{
            $("#grandtotal").val("").css("color","black");
        }
    }
}

$("#rooms, #from, #to").on("change",function(){
    grandTotal();
    $(".datepicker").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<form method="post" action="reservation.php">
    <input name="checkin" type="text" id="from" placeholder="Select a date">
    <input name="checkout" type="text" id="to"  placeholder="Select a date">
    <select onchange="ChooseContact(this)" name="numrooms" id="rooms">
        <option value="0" disabled selected>How many rooms</option>
        <option value="1">1 room</option>
        <option value="2">2 rooms</option>
    </select>
    <select class="hidden" name="price">
        <option selected="selected">200</option>
    </select>
</form>

<!-- this displays the respective values for selecting the dates, the number of rooms and finally, the "grandtotal" is shown automatically.-->
<input readonly id="totaldays" placeholder="1">
<input readonly id="totalrooms" placeholder="1">
<input readonly id="grandtotal" placeholder="-">
```

Comment: Hello Louys, I really appreciate the effort that you made and It really worked for me.  Thanks a lot, that`s what I needed.  But there is only one problem, the date is not working fine, when i select e.g. 01/10/16 to 02/10/16, it says 1 but when I change the "to" to a date after, it remains the same.

Comment: It doesn't do that in the snippet above. Compare your code with the snippet in the `calculateDuration()` around conditions `if(diff ...)`.

Comment: Thanks @Louys, one last question.  It is possible that on selecting the "from" and "to", the grandtotal is calculated and the totalrooms is assigned 1 by default.  Hence, the user will already have an idea of the price of the room and then he/she may then choose the number of rooms afterwards.

Comment: Sure, change `<input readonly id="totalrooms" placeholder="1">` for `<input readonly id="totalrooms" value="1">`... So the value will be there by default instead of a placeholder. And if you do it, you can simply remove `<option value="0" disabled selected>How many rooms</option>`. ;)

Comment: No @Louys I am very tensed. I do not know how to solve this.  The dates is now working fine and can you come online on Stackoverflow chat?

Comment: No @Louys I am very tensed. I do not know how to solve this. The dates is not working fine and can you come online on Stackoverflow chat?

Comment: I think you don't have enought rep points to chat on SO... Have a look at my profile and click on my Facebook link. ;)

Comment: Sure :) give me a minute